# How can I ignore Annotations when using Maven CPD?

Tags: maven, pmd, cpd

I know there is an option to ignoreAnnotations in the CPD CLI reference guide but I can't seem to get this to work using maven pmd:cpd plugin.  When I view the mvn pmd page it doesn't list 'ignoreAnnotations' as a usable parameter but seems like it should support if can do through CLI no??

I tried in pom like this

```
            <configuration>
                <ignoreAnnotations>true</ignoreAnnotations>             
            </configuration>
```

Thanks

Comment: The feature is indeed unsupported by the Maven plugin. You can submit an issue on https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/MPMD/issues asking for it to be included in upcoming versions.

Comment: That sucks.  Do you know if I can add separate configurations inside executions for CPD and PMD.  I might try to exclude my endpoint classes from CPD checking as thats where most of my annotations are but I don't want to exclude them from full PMD, only CPD.

Comment: As with any Maven plugin, you can define multiple <executions>, each with it's own target, phase and configuration

Comment: Yeah I tried with separate executions and configuration inside each but seemed to have no impact. Resulting build still found cpd issues inside endpoints. I noticed all examples have one configuration outside executions.

Comment: I created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MPMD-272 to support `ignoreAnnotations`.

Answer (score 0):

**Update, 2019:**

`maven-pmd-plugin` version 3.11.0 added the `ignoreAnnotations` configuration option.

See plugin documentation: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/cpd-mojo.html#ignoreAnnotations